# How can I use a foreign key and joins to get the info I need from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am currently achieving this with several steps, but it would be better if I could find what I need with one query. I think it's possible with joins and a foreign key, but I can't really figure out how it all works together.

Anyway, I have two tables `doctors` and `appointments`, one column linked with a foreign key (fk is `doctor_id` in appointments referencing `id` in `doctors`) and I need to get an appointment date, within a certain range of time and link it by the `doctor_id` to the matching id in `doctors` table and get the name and phone number from that table as well.

Here is the join statement I came up with:

```
SELECT a.doctor_id, a.appointment_date, b.last_name, b.preferred_phone 
FROM appointments a,doctors b 
WHERE a.appointment_date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Which gives me all the doctors and says their ids are all 3, which is not the case (it's an auto incrementing column), but it is the doctor `id` linked to the appointment that I need to match with. So how can I achieve that with a foreign key?

Comment: You're right, I didn't know sqlfiddle was a thing .. I was putting a table together, but ebahi gave the answer I needed. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll know for next time :p

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the condition for the join : `a.doctor_id = b.id`

```
SELECT a.doctor_id, a.appointment_date, b.last_name, b.preferred_phone 
FROM docflight_appointments a, docflight_doctors b 
WHERE a.doctor_id = b.id
  AND a.appointment_date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```